# Switching on error messages in phpThumb

Tags: php, image-processing, phpthumb

How so I do this?  I looked at phpThumb.php and the following is set, so I don't know why I am getting the error on my [demo](http://nicolaelvin.com/phpThumb/demo/phpThumb.demo.demo.php) page

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PHP error reporting and the error messages you see writing about inside the image are two different things and those settings are therefore not related.

Edit: phpThumb() has the following error configuration:

```
// * Error message configuration
$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['error_image_width']           = 400;      // default width for error images
$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['error_image_height']          = 100;      // default height for error images
$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['error_message_image_default'] = '';       // Set this to the name of a generic error image (e.g. '/images/error.png') that you want displayed in place of any error message that may occur. This setting is overridden by the 'err' parameter, which does the same thing.
$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['error_bgcolor']               = 'CCCCFF'; // background color of error message images
$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['error_textcolor']             = 'FF0000'; // color of text in error messages
$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['error_fontsize']              = 1;        // size of text in error messages, from 1 (smallest) to 5 (largest)
$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['error_die_on_error']          = true;     // die with error message on any fatal error (recommended with standalone phpThumb.php)
$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['error_silent_die_on_error']   = false;    // simply die with no output of any kind on fatal errors (not recommended)
$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['error_die_on_source_failure'] = true;     // die with error message if source image cannot be processed by phpThumb() (usually because source image is corrupt in some way). If false the source image will be passed through unprocessed, if true (default) an error message will be displayed.
```

Source: http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/index.php?source=phpThumb.config.php

Comment: @Nicola: Yes, the documentation of phpThumb() is not useful. Also the code quality isn't that well. But hey, it does work. I normally prefer wideimage and if the answer helped you, please accept it.

Comment: I needed to make thumbnails, wideimage is definitely better.

Answer (score 19):

Change this line to false in phpThumb.config.php:
$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['disable_debug'] = true;

Comment: thanks!! how dumb is it that this setting is not in the "error message configuration" part of the config? =/

Comment: This should definitely be added to the chosen answer, since that setting kills all the others if set to true